# Testing a threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have developed a solution for [Readers-Writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) using thread.

I have one monitor class and one Reader and one Writer class.Reader and writer class extend thread.

Now I am testing the code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ReadersWriters controller = new ReadersWriters();
  Reader r0=new Reader(controller);
  Reader r1=new Reader(controller);
  Reader r2=new Reader(controller);
  Reader r3=new Reader(controller);
  Writer w0=new Writer(controller);
  Writer w1=new Writer(controller);
  Writer w2=new Writer(controller);
  Writer w3=new Writer(controller);
  r0.run();
  w0.run();
  r2.run();
  r3.run();
  r1.run();
  r3.run();
  r2.run();
  w2.run();
  r1.run();
  w1.run();
  w3.run();
 }
```

And the output which I am getting is this:

```
Reader number 0 arrives
Reader number 0 starts to read
Reader number 0 finishes reading
Writer number 0 arrives
Writer number 0 starts to write
Writer number 0 finishes writing
Reader number 2 arrives
Reader number 2 starts to read
Reader number 2 finishes reading
```

...and so on.
The problem here is that I am unable to test the concurrency.Because it looks like my main program is calling Reader or writer one by one,which is not the kind of testing I am trying to achieve.

Can anyone help me please.Please feel free to ask any clarification you might need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've implemented a `Runnable`, but not wrapped it in a thread. I suspect you're calling `run()` on your `Runnable`, rather than `start()` on a thread. Check the tutorial section on [defining/starting a thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

You can't reliably test multi-threaded code in unit tests and the like. It could work one time, or many times, and only fail once in a million test cases (or immediately in production). I would favour thread-safe coding techniques (e.g. writing immutable objects), static code analysis tools (e.g. PMD), and perhaps [code reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you're unsure.

Answer (score 1):

you should call(invoke) threads run method using start method. `public void run()` should be called using `thread.start()`.

```
r0.run();
```

should be

```
r0.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending `Thread` and calling `Thread.run()` you should implement the `Runnable` interface and use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run/control the threads.